# Add more rows to the title field

Tags: entities

The title field only has 1 row for text.  I want to expand it vertically with more rows.

How to add more rows?

Comment: Do you want many title for a single node ?

Comment: 1 title, but more rows.  Like the "Long text" field with the widget "text area (multiple rows)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() function implementation.
 * @param unknown_type $form
 * @param unknown_type $form_state

 */
function yourmodule_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Add your own function to the array of validation callbacks
    $form['title'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => 'Title1',
            '#required' => 1,
    );
    return $form;
}
```

I have created for article node type. You can use same for other node typw also.
I have used [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) API function.

Comment: where is the right place to put this code? thank you

Comment: If you have created any custom module then you can write in it. otherwise create a separate module with any name and write this code in .module file and dont forget to replace yourmodule with module name